# How to allow only one type in Haskell getLine

Tags: haskell, typing

I have this code that adds a person to my txt. But in the name, for example, I want to allow only letters. As well as in age, I just want to allow numbers

```
add = do
    putStrLn "Name:"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Age:"
    age <- getLine
    let new =  (name ++ " "++ idade ++ "\n")
    appendFile "funcionarios.txt" new
    putStrLn "Success!"
```

Comment: What should happen in case somebody enters something invalid?

Comment: One exception message, and repeating the getLine.

Comment: Make a function which wraps getLine, and validates the input with something like `isLetter` from [Data.Char](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isLetter)

Comment: I know this isn't the point, but in any real application you should be very careful about the restrictions you put on names. Whatever "all names should" rule you come up with is pretty likely to be violated by some actual person's name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `Read` class source:

```
class Read a where
  readsPrec :: Int -> ReadS a
  -- (...)
```

What's this `ReadS`? From [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=readS):

```
type ReadS a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

This allows us to write reads that can fail:

```
maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead str = case readsPrec 0 str of
    [(a, "")] -> Just a
--    ^   ^---- no remaining input string
--    |- output
    _         -> Nothing
```

It's then a simple case of modifying your IO. Here's a quick dirty example:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter an integer:"

  let loop = do
        str <- getLine
        maybe loop return (maybeRead str :: Maybe Int)

  num <- loop
  print $ num + 1
```

Comment: Nice! Thx. How can I use this example to only allow letters?

Comment: @JoaoAlbuquerque modify the loop. Also, [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) `all` and `isLetter`.